# pyserial arduino bytearray decoding issue

Tags: python, c++, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to interface with an arduino sending serial data over usb to record EMG signals as fast as possible. Previously I was using an audio card adc as it was easy to directly interface with the adc sampling register but now I am trying to make my device completely wireless. As a result I have one end sampling via arduino, sending the data via rf transceiver, then serially transferring. The arduino side is writing a byte over the channel. Here is the test code:

```
void setup() { 

Serial.begin(115200);
  timer = micros();
}

void loop() {
  //timeSync(loopTime);

  int val = analogRead(1)-512;  
  sendToPC(&val);
}

void sendToPC(int* data)
{
  byte* byteData = (byte*)(data);
  Serial.write(byteData, 2);
}
```

here is my python snippet

```
com = "COM3"
baud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(com, baud)
res = bytearray(4)
#ser.readinto(res)

tik = time.time()
rec = []
while(time.time() - tik < 2):
    ser.readinto(res)
    value = struct.unpack('>HH', res)
    rec.extend(value)
```

So when I force the analog pin to 5V, i read back 512 (as it should). Now if i create a divider with one end at Vcc (5V), and the other end my incoming signal, I for some reason get a 4 byte number instead of 2 from the decoding (ie 0xFFe0, or something along those lines).

I am using the divider as the incoming data can be positive or negative, so my thought process was in doing the divider, I can record negative values. However it seems to be messing up conversions! Any ideas (code wise/HW wise?)

EDIT: I realize the 511 is wrong for straight 5V (should be 1023), however I do the bit shift before i send it out (for example, if the signal is 0V, divider would give 2.5V ~ 512 when quantized. therefore the -512 would give 0V)

Comment: What do you mean "4 byte number"? You are reading 4 bytes and unpacking them as 2 unsigned 16-bit ints. If you want negative numbers, that obviously won't work.

Comment: unpacking for int with struct.unpack requires 4 bytes as an argument I believe. it unpacks into a tuple of (2 bytes, 2 bytes). Unfortunately sometimes it seems the LSB starts thats the issue. Negative number is easy. (val-512)/1023*5 will give the negative number, since the divider keeps voltage positive.

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution is kinda janky, but here it is.

So i noticed that sometimes when I collected data by reading two bytes i get a byte array in the form:

bytearray(b'xFF/x01/xFF/x01')

By checking if the first byte (unsigned) read is >1023, I flush the serial input and output buffer, read one byte, and then continue reading two bytes:

```
rxbuffer =b''
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
time.sleep(2)
tik = time.time()
rec = []
while(time.time() - tik < 1):
    rxbuffer = ser.read(2)
    if(int.from_bytes(rxbuffer, 'big', signed=True) > 1023):
        print("out of sync")
        tik = time.time()
        ser.flushInput()
        ser.flushOutput()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        ser.read(1)
        continue

    conv = int.from_bytes(rxbuffer, 'big', signed=True)
    rec.append(conv)
    print(conv)
```